# Rails 4 on Heroku: web dyno serving old assets, while other serve new

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4, assets

This issue has just recently come up in our last several pushes to Heroku since upgrading to Rails 4. My application has two web dynos. What I've been able to find through troubleshooting is that I'm having issues with one web dyno loading an older compiled CSS file when there are newer compiled assets available. The other web dyno will then serve the current, desired application CSS. I should state that we compile our assets before pushing to heroku.

What I've found is that the web dyno that serves the old assets, always serves the old assets. I've tried deleting web.2 and then recreating it, and the issue persists. I've even gone and created 8 web dynos and then logged them to see if they served new or old assets. In that test, about half of the dynos consistenly served old assets, and half served new.

Restarting the individual dynos doesn't seem to help either.

We're running Rails 4 on Ruby 2.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to try changing the `config.assets.version` attribute in your `config/application.rb` file.  I've run into this problem where some assets are stale and changing this value from `1.0` to `1.1` has solved it for me:

config/application.rb

`config.assets.version = '1.1'`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Expiring the assets alone didn't seems to work. I did the expiration along with `rake assets:clobber`, so then the app would have no old assets to fall back to.

I repushed  with clobbered, expired and recompiled assets and both dynos are serving the latest compilation's assets

I'm still at a loss as for the root cause though.